# Get description columns Oracle use sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

To connect to BBDD (Oracle) through Python, I use the sqlalchemy library.
With the connection.execute(query) command I get the data without problems but I am not able to get the description that each field has.

For example, for the variable called ID_Customer=1111 and it has as description: it is the customer identifier.

How can I get that description?

Thanks!

Comment: [`Column.comment`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.comment)? There's no any description behind every expression you may build in the SQL statement `select` list

Comment: Using the sqlalchemy library, is there any way to achieve it?